# "if" statement block doesn't work correctly

Tags: java, if-statement, objectinputstream

I don't actually know what's up here, but I am writing server-client application and client sends a string to the server. I need to send the string "x" to the server, so it starts running code1, but when I do it, server runs code3. The funniest thing is `System.out.println(x);` prints "a" in the console.

Here is a fragment of server code(runs on win7, javac compiler):

```
sInput = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

String x = (String) sInput.readObject();
System.out.println(x);

if (x == "a") {
   /* 
    * code1
    */
} else if (x == "b") {
   /* 
    * code2
    */
} else {
   /* 
    * code3
    */
}
```

And this is what client does(runs osx, javac compiler):

```
sInput = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
sOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

String x = "a";
sOutput.writeObject(x);
```

How should I sort it out?

P.S. I know about exception declaration, they are removed to make the code shorter.

Comment: Don't compare String values using `==`. Use `equals()`.

Comment: I hate it when people say that the tool they are using is wrong without any proof. How long has Java been around? How long have you been programming it? Your `if` statement works perfectly well. Your expectations are wrong.

Comment: Using `==` instead of `equals` is a classic newbie mistake.  You'll probably make it two or three more times, but fix in your head the point that there's (almost) always a logical explanation, and it's (almost) always due to a "stupid" mistake.

Comment: And it's better to use the Yoda form, like `if ("a".equals(x))` in case `x` is `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use equals method to compare the values of two strings. See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for more information.

Comment: For future reference, the correct course of action here would be to flag the post as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

The “==” operator is used to compare 2 objects, it checks to see if the objects refer to the same place in memory. In other words, it checks to see if the 2 object names are basically references to the same memory location.

The equals method is actually meant to compare the contents of 2 objects, and not their location in memory. Source - http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/

And since Strings are non-mutable and use a different memory location every time they are instantiated, they are better always compared using equals() method :)